# loookup server IPs the website runs on with nslookup error - Got recursion not available from 192.168.1.1, trying next server

Tags: macos, terminal, dns, webserver

I would like to lookup servers cnn runs on for educational purposes.

I issued `nslookup www.cnn.com` command in terminal and got an error:

```
;; Got recursion not available from 192.168.1.1, trying next server
Server:     2a00:ee0:d::13
Address:    2a00:ee0:d::13#53

Non-authoritative answer:
www.cnn.com canonical name = turner.map.fastly.net.
Name:   turner.map.fastly.net
Address: 23.235.43.73
```

192.168.1.1 looks like an address in a home network.

Although it lists one server, I don't believe they use just on. Is there something else I must do or is looking up the servers cnn runs on disabled by cnn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer you got was correct.

`www.cnn.com canonical name = turner.map.fastly.net.`

A *canonical name*, or [CNAME record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record#Terminology_of_CNAME_vs_.22canonical_name.22) is a record in DNS servers that define an *alias* for another domain.  In this case "www.cnn.com" points to the domain "turner.map.fastly.net".

As for your 192.168.1.1 server, that's most likely your router that is configured as a DNS cache or DNSMasq server.  The error message is fine, it's just telling you that the DNS server that you have listed *first* in the list of DNS servers doesn't support recursion.  It's not an issue.

My personal router is configured as a DNS relay and I don't get the error because it passes all DNS requests except for anything with my defined domain out to the public DNS servers.

Comment: Isn't the OP's router a DNS relay and you have a normal DNS server?

Comment: @klanomath  No, I specifically set up a DNS relay (pfSense).  Many new routers come with DNS built in (DNSMasq)